# Calculator Which Accepts Both String and Integer Inputs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating a calculator in C++ which will allow the user to enter either integers or corresponding lexical values from zero to ten (i.e. both "Five" and 5 are valid input).

The user enters two values and then provides a simple arithmetic operator (+, -, *, /). This part works fine. I have a function which gets each input from the user (shown below).

```
int grabUserValue(std::vector<std::string> vals)
{
    // If input is int, immediately return int value
    // Clear input stream if not
    int intInput = 0;

    if (std::cin >> intInput) {
        return intInput;
    }
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    // Otherwise store input in a string and return the
    //corresponding value based upon index in lexical vector
    std::string strInput = " ";
    std::cin >> strInput;
        for (auto x = 0; x < vals.size(); x++)
        {
            if (vals[x] == strInput)
            {
                return x;
            }
        }

        // If neither succeeds, return the value -1
        return -1;
}
```

It works by first reading into an integer, and returning the value if this is successful. If not, the input stream is cleared and the user input is entered into a string. This is then compared against a vector containing the strings "Zero" to "Ten". It moves through and compares the input to each string, and returns the corresponding index if it matches (therefore providing an equivalent integer value to use for a calculation). The vector and function call are as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> lexicalValues = { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUTNUMBER; i++)
        {
            if (inputCounter == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "Enter first value: ";
                userValOne = grabUserValue(lexicalValues);
                inputCounter++;
            }
            if (inputCounter == 2)
            {
                std::cout << "Enter second value: ";
                userValTwo = grabUserValue(lexicalValues);
                inputCounter++;
            }
            if (inputCounter == 3)
            {
                std::cout << "Specify operation: ";
                std::cin >> userOperation;
                inputCounter++;
            }
        }
```

If the user enters integers, the input is read into `userValOne/userValTwo` successfully and the calculation completes. If equivalent strings are entered, the function always returns -1, causing the answer to be incorrect. 
I've checked and re-checked the input function, and can't figure out why it never matches the string input to the string inside the `lexicalValues` vector. I've definitely narrowed it down to something running incorrectly inside that `for` loop since the rest of the code works perfectly in all other cases.

Any help massively appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: You should also allow either '+' or 'plus'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't figure out why it never matches the string input to the string inside the lexicalValues vector.

A simple print in the for loop shows what the problem is.

```
 std::cout << "'" << vals[x] << "' '"<< strInput << "'\n";
```

```
'Zero' 'ero'
'One' 'ero'
...
```

You don't get the char back that was used to determine that it was not a number. We can fix this by checking ourselves.

```
std::cin >> std::ws;
auto ch = std::cin.peek();
if (! isalpha(ch) ){
    if (std::cin >> intInput) {
        return intInput;
    }
} ...
```

Then the comparison in the for loop works as expected.
See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2512ea6b871acca)

Comment: Huge thankyou - Can't believe I didn't know about this (but you learn a little every day).
`std::cin.ignore()` was also causing some issues. I thought it prevented the input stream from accepting inputs for some short time (don't know why though). 
Thanks again.